# Store Complex data with SequenceFile Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, sequencefile

my question is how to generate a sequenceFile from text to output some format like this:

```
<string, string>,<double, double>
```

the left side is the key, and the right side is the value.

Comment: Can you provide clarification on what you're trying to do?  Do you need to: 1.) create a SequenceFile and can already make your compound key; or 2.) are having trouble creating a compound key ?  Also, what did you try or what has already failed you?

Comment: What is your input and how does it look?

Comment: my input is something like this: tfidf1@doc1 tfidf2@doc2, so I want to generate the output stored in sequenceFile <doc1,doc2>,<tfidf1,tfidf2>